# RadioButtons with TextView in RadioGroup

Tags: android, textview, radio-button, radio-group

Is it possible to add TextView below RadioButton in RadioGroup in any other way than extending and creating my custom RadioButton?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, its possible. See below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="btn1" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="btn2" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="sample text" />

    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Sample output**:

[image]

Comment: The problem begins though, when I need to put TextView between two RadioButtons - it is not possible to have it under RadioGroup, because the selection will be disabled and it starts doing funky things.

Comment: Could you please show screen of text between and in the bottom? Can't make it work :(

Comment: I mean, sure the layout works just great, but functionality loses precision - if I check third RadioButton, it does weird things...

Comment: just move the TextView between two CheckBoxes. thats what i did and it worked

Answer (score 0):

You can remove RadioGroup from your XML and add radio buttons one by one.
Look at this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

  <RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:text="RadioButton" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/radioButton1"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

  <RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="RadioButton" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Yes, but then I can't work with RadioButtons like with group - which involves lot of coding with own RadioButton mechanism...

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use another tricky solution. Create a gap between two radio buttons with padding or margin and then put textView on the gap.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="78dp" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="RadioButton" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RadioButton" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RadioButton" />

</RadioGroup>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Look at the image:]

Comment: nope, not working, try removing center_horizontal...aligns itself with top of the screen...